# Rails Haml checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

stupid questions, how I can rewrite my code in haml?

```
<% for role in Role.find(:all) %>
<div>
  <%= check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.roles.include?(role) %>
  <%= role.name %>
</div>
```

And where I can found haml examples, like http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
- for role in Role.find(:all)
  %div
    = check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.roles.include?(role)
    = role.name
```

I just used http://html2haml.heroku.com/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not too late, but always you could run the `html2haml` command. Something like: `html2haml app/views/layout/application.html.erb app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`